# Batch File search token for string

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a different output to a file based on what the first token contains as these can be different, is this possible?

I am writing out a table based on the results of a query session command across multiple tables, this leaves me with a output like below

```
Server 1 
                   User1               2  Disc                        
Server 2 
                   User1               1  Disc                        
 rdp-tcp#0         User2               4  Active  rdpwd               
Server 3 Offline 
Server 4 
                   User1               8  Disc                        
                   User2               9  Disc                        
                   User3              10  Disc
```

The snippet of code i currently have to write this out is:

```
>>%2 echo ^<table class="tftable" border="1"^>
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
>>%2 echo ^<tr^>^<td^>%%a^</td^>^<td^>%%b^</td^>^<td^>%%c^</td^>^<td^>%%d^</td^>^</tr^>
)   
>>%2 echo ^</table^>
```

I want to use an IF Else statement to adjust the table rows i echo out to the file based on whether the line starts with the string 'Server' or 'rdp' as the only output i want in the table is server name and below that the username and state of their session.

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: With delims set to nothing there won't be tokens (which you could write `tokens=1-4`)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Is it possible to read what is included in the first token and to see if it matches a string? So does it match 'Server', if so write out tokens A and C, if it matches 'rdp' write out tokens A and B etc.

Comment: Is the format exactly as in your example? Server on 1st line and then user 1 etc on the next?

Comment: If you are simply tring to output a file in html format which lists the Server with its logged in UserNames, IDs and States, perhaps PowerShell might be better for you than batch files. Take a look at [this](https://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/01/quick-hit-find-currently-logged-on-users/) and [this](https://discoposse.com/2012/10/20/finding-rdp-sessions-on-servers-using-powershell/) example to see if they provide inspiration. If so, take a look at the [ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127059.aspx).

Comment: Yes, it's the result of the following

Comment: FOR /F %%i IN (AXServers.txt) DO (
 ping -n 1 %%i | find "TTL="
 IF errorlevel 1 (
  echo %%i Offline >> currentsessions.txt
 ) ELSE (
  echo %%i >> currentsessions.txt
  QUERY SESSION /SERVER:%%i |findstr /c:"Active" /c:"Disc" | findstr /V "services" >> currentsessions.txt)
)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't see how i could add that in the code boxes as original post lets you.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there instead.

Comment: I would suggest in the first instance that you take the information from the comments above and use it in your question area. When the question and task are clear in the question area, you have a greater possibility of attracting relevant solutions. You should then delete the irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo ^<table class="tftable" border="1"^>
set "server="
for /f "delims=" %%A in (currentsessions.txt) do call :rawline "%%~A"
echo ^</table^>

:rawline
setlocal
set "line=%~1"
if not defined line exit /b

set "t1=%line:~0,18%"
call :trim t1 "%t1%"

if not defined t1 set "t1=%server%"
if "%line:~19,18%" == "" endlocal & set "server=%t1%" & exit /b
set "td=<tr><td>%t1%</td>"
call set /p "=%%td%%" <nul
if not "%t1: Offline=%" == "%t1%" (echo ^</tr^>) & exit /b

set "t2=%line:~19,18%"
call :trim t2 "%t2%"
set "td=<td>%t2%</td>"
call set /p "=%%td%%" <nul

set "t3=%line:~38,2%"
call :trim t3 "%t3%"
set "td=<td>%t3%</td>"
call set /p "=%%td%%" <nul

set "t4=%line:~42,7%"
call :trim t4 "%t4%"
set "td=<td>%t4%</td>"
call set /p "=%%td%%" <nul

set "t5=%line:~50%"
call :trim t5 "%t5%"
set "td=<td>%t5%</td></tr>"
call set /p "=%%td%%" <nul
echo.

if defined t1 endlocal & set "server=%t1%"
exit /b

:trim
setlocal
set "line=%~2"
:ltrim
if not defined line endlocal & set "%~1=" & exit /b
if "%line:~,1%" == " " set "line=%line:~1%" & goto :ltrim
:rtrim
if not defined line endlocal & set "%~1=" & exit /b
if "%line:~-1%" == " " set "line=%line:~0,-1%" & goto :rtrim
endlocal & set "%~1=%line%"
exit /b
```

Handles the read lines raw so that positional delimiting can be done.

The positional handling is done by i.e.

```
set "t1=%line:~0,18%"
```

This starts from character 0 and gets the following 18 characters.

Whitespace is trimmed from the data using the call to `:trim`.

The `call set /p "=..." <nul` lines are to print the data to console without
a newline so the next data item can be appended on the same line.

The `server` variable is only updated as needed so that i.e.
`Server 4` uses the same server 3 times so a need to retain
last known server was needed to complete following rows.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i've now applied this and it's working great.